# Copiar lista enlazada en otra JAVA

Tags: java, lista, nodos

¿Cómo podría pasar la lista auxiliar compuesta por nodos a la lista oficial compuesta también por nodos?
Ejemplo:

**Lista oficial**
 - 5, 7, 9, 1

**Lista auxiliar**
 - 4, 3, 8

```
       *Función que para que la lista auxiliar pase a ser la oficial*
```

**Lista oficial(solución)**
 - 4, 3, 8

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Además de formular tu pregunta, sería recomendable al menos que muestres el código que has intentado para que te podamos ayudar en tus posibles errores.

Comment: He visto algunas preguntas que has hecho y justamente las eliminaste, solo quería recomendarte, que cuando trates de crear tu propio LinkedList (sin usar la API de Java), que la hagas [genérica](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), de este modo reutilizas código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una solución:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(-5);
lista.add(7);
lista.add(9);
lista.add(1);
ArrayList<Integer> listaAux = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listaAux.add(-4);
listaAux.add(3);
listaAux.add(8);
System.out.println(lista);// la lista irginal con los sus campos originales - 5, 7, 9, 1
System.out.println(listaAux);// la lista axiliar con sus campos originales
lista = new ArrayList<Integer>(listaAux);// copiamos la lista auxiliar en la original
System.out.println(lista);//lista original con los campos de la lista axiliar  - 4, 3, 8
```

Espero te ayude en algo.